# Attach doesnt work. ERROR: The following objects are masked from Umfrage

Tags: r

Hi I am really new to this, but normally "attach" worked for me and now suddenly it doesn`t anymore. "View" and everythingelse works though. 
The Error message is always:

"The following objects are masked from Umfrage (pos = 3):

```
ats, browser, c_0001, c_0002, cleaned, date_of_first_mail,
date_of_last_access, datetime, device_type, dispcode, duration,
external_lfdn, flash, hflip, javascript, language, lastpage, lfdn,
output_mode, page_history, participant_brand, participant_browser,
participant_browser_version, participant_city, participant_continent,
participant_country, participant_device, participant_isbot,
participant_model, participant_os, participant_region, quality, quota,
quota_assignment, referer, rts3186712, rts3186716, rts3186726,
rts3186728, rts3189018, rts3189022, rts3203949, rts3203954, rts3203956,
rts3203960, rts3203962, rts3204143, session_id, tester, v_17, v_18,
v_19_1_1, v_19_1_1_1, v_19_1_1_2, v_19_1_1_3, v_19_1_1_4, v_19_1_1_5,
v_19_1_1_6, v_19_1_2, v_19_1_2_1, v_19_1_2_2, v_19_1_2_3, v_19_1_2_4,
v_19_1_2_5, v_19_1_2_6, v_19_1_3, v_19_1_4, v_19_1_5, v_19_1_6,
v_19_10_1, v_19_10_1_1, v_19_10_1_2, v_19_10_1_3, v_19_10_1_4,
v_19_10_1_5, v_19_10_1_6,..........................."
```

I really need attach, do you know how to solve that problem?

Comment: Simply don't use `attach`. You really don't need it and it can easily get you into trouble.

Comment: Looks like the object was already attached. So perhaps you forgot to `detach()` at some point.